# I need a 2-dimensional array with one dynamic dimension in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a 2-dimensions array, where there are 8 "rows" but "columns" are not predetermined

someting along this example:

```
[0], ['mum', 'dad', 'uncle']
[1], ['brother', 'sister']
[2], ['friend', 'colleague', 'boss', 'employee']
.... and so on
```

than I have to scroll the first index (1 to 8) and read every possible values of all columns (for each "index" I have the count of how many elements are in it.

and I need to read using something like

```
ary[2][3]    --->that would return "boss"
```

Following other exampes I am using

```
unsigned char (*ary)[n] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char[8][n]));
```

but it doesn't compile and gives:

> error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'unsigned char **'
>         with an rvalue of type 'void *'

HOw do I declare and read this kind of array correctly in C++ ?

Comment: `::std::array<::std::vector<::std::string>, 8>`

Comment: While you can use raw memory management and pointers in C++, it's recommended that you use types like `std::vector` or `std::array` instead, since they don't have the same weirdnesses with pointer decay.

Comment: You ought to practice constructing *one* dynamic array, before you attempt several at once. And it behooves you to start with a simpler type than `char[]` or `string` or whatever that is.

Comment: `'mum'` will cause much wailing and gnashing of teeth in C++ because it will try to create a multi-byte character rather than a string. You will probably get a compiler warning, but I don't think I can guarantee that. You might get no diagnostic at all and spend an afternoon slamming your head against a wall while screaming, "Why? WHY?". I recommend `"mum"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of rows will be known at compile time you can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
std::array<std::vector<std::string>, number_of_rows>
```

You can also use

```
std::vector<std::string>[number_of_rows]
```

But working with raw arrays is not as convenient as `std::array`.

If the number of rows will not be known until runtime you can have a vector of vectors like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using C++, avoid using `malloc`. Prefer to use `new` instead.

Assuming `n` is a compile time constant, you can use:

```
unsigned char (*ary)[n] = new unsigned char[8][n];
```

If `n` is a run time variable, you most likely need to use:

```
unsigned char (*ary)[8] = new unsigned char[n][8];
```

You can avoid the problems of dealing with dynamically allocated memory if:

1. You use a `std::array` for the array of `unsigned char`.
2. You use a `std::vector` to capture the dynamic nature of the data.

---

```
std::struct<std::array<unsigned char, 8>> ary(n);
```